# Should I use ListView or DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i need to show two columns of data on listview or datagridview, but i want if the data reach the maximum height of the listview or datagridview, the next data should appear beside of the 1st list of data and not continue downwards.

[image]

Comment: That's not how either of those controls work.  You can have a `ListView` wrap horizontally but not in `Details` view.  You can also have a `ListBox` do that but it won't display multiple columns per item either.  You may just have to roll your own.

Comment: in short it is not possible in vb.net?

Comment: Where did I say that?  It's just not going to happen with those standard controls because that's not how they are designed to work.  You could use a `ListView` or a `DataGridView` but, as far as they were concerned, they would be displaying a list of items vertically and it would be up to you to add extra columns as required to make it look to the user as though the data was wrapping horizontally.  You can do that if you want but it's not for us to teach you how.  If you try to do it and encounter a specific issue, that the sort of thing we can help with here.

Comment: Also, VB.NET is a language.  Don't confuse it with a technology.  What you want to do will be tedious in Windows Forms but would likely be much easier using WPF.  Both technologies support VB.NET.